# Show Column and line chart together in drill down using highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to show column chart and line chart in combination in drill down using highcharts , but not getting success, but when applying this without drill down, it is easily showing both charts.

I am using this code:

```
            $(function () {
                    var defaultTitle = "Total Distance By Site";
                    var drilldownTitle = "Ave. Journey Distance By Vehicle Type";
                    var ydrillupTitle = "km";
                    var ydrilldownTitle = "";
                    var xdrillupcat = ['Site A', 'Site B', 'Site C', 'Site D'];
                    var xdrilldowncat = ['Waste', 'Medium Truck', 'Mid-Sized', 'Car'];

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            renderTo: 'totdisbyloc',
                            events: {
                                drilldown: function(e) {
                                    chart.setTitle({ text: drilldownTitle });
                                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(xdrilldowncat);
                                    chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                                        text: ydrilldownTitle
                                    });
                                },
                                drillup: function(e) {
                                    chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle });
                                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(xdrillupcat);
                                    chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                                        text: ydrillupTitle
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: defaultTitle
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: ''
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: xdrillupcat
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            allowDecimals: false,
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: ydrillupTitle
                            }
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                stacking: 'normal',
                                showInLegend: true
                            }
                        },

                        series:[
                            {
                                name:'Car', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                    pointFormat: '<span>Car</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total: {point.stackTotal}<br/>'
                                },
                                data: [{
                                    name: "Car",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Car",
                                    y: 5,
                                    drilldown: "Car"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Mid-Sized",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Mid-Sized",
                                    y: 4,
                                    drilldown: "Mid-Sized"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Medium Truck",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Medium Truck",
                                    y: 3,
                                    drilldown: "Medium Truck"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Large Truck",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Large Truck",
                                    y: 6,
                                    drilldown: "Large Truck"
                                }] 
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Mid-Sized', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                    pointFormat: '<span>Mid-Sized</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total: {point.stackTotal}<br/>'
                                },
                                data: [{
                                    name: "Car",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Car",
                                    y: 2,
                                    drilldown: "Car"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Mid-Sized",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Mid-Sized",
                                    y: 2,
                                    drilldown: "Mid-Sized"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Medium Truck",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Medium Truck",
                                    y: 3,
                                    drilldown: "Medium Truck"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Large Truck",
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance By Large Truck",
                                    y: 2,
                                    drilldown: "Large Truck"
                                }] 
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Medium Truck', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                    pointFormat: '<span>Medium Truck</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total: {point.stackTotal}<br/>'
                                },
                                data: [{
                                    name: "Car",
                                    y: 4,
                                    drilldown: "Car"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Mid-Sized",
                                    y: 5,
                                    drilldown: "Mid-Sized"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Medium Truck",
                                    y: 3,
                                    drilldown: "Medium Truck"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Large Truck",
                                    y: 7,
                                    drilldown: "Large Truck"
                                }]
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Large Truck', 
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                    pointFormat: '<span>Large Truck</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total: {point.stackTotal}<br/>'
                                },
                                data: [{
                                    name: "Car",
                                    y: 5,
                                    drilldown: "Car"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Mid-Sized",
                                    y: 3,
                                    drilldown: "Mid-Sized"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Medium Truck",
                                    y: 4,
                                    drilldown: "Medium Truck"
                                }, {
                                    name: "Large Truck",
                                    y: 7,
                                    drilldown: "Large Truck"
                                }]
                            }
                        ],
                        drilldown: {
                            series: [
                                {
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance by Car",
                                    showInLegend: false,
                                    name: "Car",
                                    type: "column",
                                    id: "Car",
                                    plotOptions: {
                                        series: {
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                        pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        ["Large Truck", 24],
                                        ["Medium Truck", 17],
                                        ["Mid-Sized", 8],
                                        ["Car", 10]
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance by Car",
                                    showInLegend: false,
                                    name: "Car",
                                    type: "spline",
                                    id: "Car",
                                    plotOptions: {
                                        series: {
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                        pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        ["Large Truck", 22],
                                        ["Medium Truck", 15],
                                        ["Mid-Sized", 6],
                                        ["Car", 8]
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance by Mid-Sized",
                                    name: "Mid-Sized",
                                    showInLegend: false,
                                    type: "column",
                                    id: "Mid-Sized",
                                    plotOptions: {
                                        series: {
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                        pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        ["Large Truck", 24],
                                        ["Medium Truck", 17],
                                        ["Mid-Sized", 8],
                                        ["Car", 10]
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance by Medium Truck",
                                    name: "Medium Truck",
                                    showInLegend: false,
                                    type: "column",
                                    id: "Medium Truck",
                                    plotOptions: {
                                        series: {
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                        pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        ["Large Truck", 24],
                                        ["Medium Truck", 17],
                                        ["Mid-Sized", 8],
                                        ["Car", 10]
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title: "Ave. Journey Distance by Large Truck",
                                    name: "Large Truck",
                                    showInLegend: false,
                                    type: "column",
                                    id: "Large Truck",
                                    plotOptions: {
                                        series: {
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{}</span>',
                                        pointFormat: '<span>{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                                    },
                                    data: [
                                        ["Large Truck", 24],
                                        ["Medium Truck", 17],
                                        ["Mid-Sized", 8],
                                        ["Car", 10],
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        // ... more options
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "not getting success"?

Comment: I am not getting both column and line chart together in drill down.

Comment: For reference http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo in this url example is of grouped columns with line chart, but i want single columns with line chart in drill down series not in main series.

Comment: Do you mean that this kind of demo doens't work http://jsfiddle.net/18d8kora/ or something different?

Comment: I want this functionality in drilldown series, can you help ?

Comment: You can achieve that, but then you should disable labels drilldown, because in that case both series are drilled. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/18d8kora/1/

Comment: The last one url demo you shared, i don't want to show line chart initially, it should be shown when we click on any column bar then this line chart should be shown with the column chart related to clicked column in drill down, Plz explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic drill down it is possible to use `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` function for each series and call `chart.applyDrilldown();` at the end of drill down.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zn1o2xzL/